# Running Neo4j query in nodejs returns "undefined"

Tags: node.js, neo4j, undefined

I am trying to run a query against neo4j database from nodejs. here is the code inside my app.get in nodejs:

```
var query = 'match (t {name:"Tom Hanks"}) return t';
    var params={limit: 10};
    cypher(query,params,cb);
```

And here is the cypher function definition for executing the query:

```
function cypher(query,params,cb) {
      request.post({uri:txUrl,
        json:{statements:[{statement:query,parameters:params}]}},
        function(err,res) { cb(err,res.body);});
    }
```

Finally, this is the cb function definition:

```
var cb = function(err,data) { 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
};
```

And I set the database path as follows:

```
var txUrl = 'http://localhost:7474/db/data';
```

After running the code in node js. I just get the error "undefined" in the console. It is hard to debug with this clue. Before this I got similar errors of form "variable x is undefined". But now, I am stuck. Does anyone have any idea to find the source of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should output the `err` parameter, then you should also see the error message. 
Try to get up to speed with javascript/node and it's conventions first, that will save you such misunderstandings.

Your URL is wrong, it has to be:

```
var txUrl = 'http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit';
```

Also your params are not used any where.

And you should use a *Label* in your match, like `:Person` or `:Actor`

I think you would be better off using a driver for Javascript, see http://neo4j.com/developer/javascript

Comment: Thank you Michael. I revised the URL accordingly. And using the error parameter now, I am getting the following error: [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED] code: 'ECONNREFUSED', errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' } I think I should go for one of the drivers that you introduced. Do you recommend going for node-neo4j?

Comment: Seems that my Neo4J Service was stopped for a reason. I started it and now it works flawlessly. But still, I think doing these stuff with a driver would be better. So, which driver do you recommend? node-neo4j or neo4j-js?

Comment: I'd recommend node-neo4j v2